# Html5 data attribute not updating when javascript polling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm polling the status of a background process. I'm trying to use the HTML5 data attribute to pass the `:status`(model attribute)  of the background process to the js polling function. The status successfully updates when the background job is finished, but my javascript is not retrieving the updated status.

```
<div class="report" data-report-id="<%= @report.id %>" data-report-completed="<%= @report.completed? %>">
  <% if @report.completed? %>
```

I'm certain that the `@report.completed?` method works correctly. Here is my javascript. Accessing the `data-report-completed` attribute is not returning the updated status.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".report-loading").length > 0) {
    showActivityIndicator();
    console.log("Loading...");
    setTimeout(checkReportStatus, 3000);
  }
});

function checkReportStatus() {
  var report_completed = $(".report").attr("data-report-completed");
  if (report_completed == true) {
    console.log("Completed");
    var report_id = $(".report").attr("data-report-id");
    location.reload();
  }
  else {
    console.log("In progress...");
    setTimeout(checkReportStatus, 3000);
  }
}
```

Comment: why ain't you using `data()` instead of `attr()` ?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with jQuery. What's the difference? I changed to `data()` and still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're comparing a boolean but you should be checking the string value as you're checking an attribute value.  Try changing your comparison like so:

`if (report_completed === 'true') {`

if you need to get a value back from the server to update your html you can do something like the following ajax call.:

```
function checkUpdated(){
   $.get('pathToCheckIfYourJobIsDone',function(isUpdated){ // isUpdated is what your server response
      if(isUpdated){
         $(".report").attr("data-report-completed",true);
         // do whatever else you want to do when it is complete.
      }else
      {
           setTimeout(checkUpdated,3000);
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: It didn't fix my issue, but you're right about it returning a string instead of a bool.

Comment: How are you setting the data-report-completed property?

Comment: I'm using a delayed_job success hook to set the property to the `Report` model. I've confirmed that this works... I think I'm missing something in javascript to actually refresh the data-report-completed property which would then check the `report.completed?` condition again and return the updated value.

Comment: do you have an ajax call updating in the background that you haven't added to your question?

Comment: No I don't. I'm using delayed_job to process data in the background, but I've included all of my code involved in the front-end. Can you point me to an example? I have very little experience with jquery.

Comment: the html won't ever update on its own even if you have a job on the server processing on the backend.  I'll update my answer to give an example...